# http to https redirection when you have not access to server

Tags: php, http, redirect, https

i have a website with a free hosting plan, so i have not access to the server, and the redirection with htaccess does not work either.
So i do this to redirect my users if they are not under the https protocol (do you think it is good enough or can i add some stuffs to it in order to make it better? ) :

```
$protocol = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"];

if (!strstr($protocol, 'https')){
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: _"and the redirection with htaccess does not work either"_ - Because the host doesn't support htaccess or because you don't know how? Btw, are you using CloudFlare?

Comment: Could be because AllowOverride isn't set for the webdirs?  As for the OP, does $_SERVER['HTTPS'] not yield a value?